# how to make the edit text value remain on the same page after comming from one activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-edittext

with the topic name everyone should be confused let me explain my question.i have two activity in first activity there is two edit text and two button one button is **next** and other is **set**. if i enter some values in the edit text and press the **next** button it will go so next page. In the second page after making some process and come to the first page when i press a button from second activity the values in the edit text in the first Activity will be disappear.my question that is there any solution to make the edit text value remain same in the page even after coming from the other activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save your values in your EditTexts like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putStringExtra("editText1","text to save");
```

and you could start the 2nd activity for a result. When you return from the second activity, you can retrieve the values by using the getStringExtra() method

Answer (score 2):

Use SharedPreferences to save the values in the edit text when the button is clicked, then reset them in `onResume()`.

Comment: thank you sir your answer is also correct if i have the permission from stack overflow to  to approve two answers  i will defiantly approve this answer. but the answer from jrom is more easier.thank you for the replay.(shared preference is also an solution for my question)